# Is NuGet suitable for downloading runtime binaries?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Is NuGet suitable for pulling down assemblies which are not required for compilation, but are at runtime? I have a Visual Studio solution which contains a number of NuGet packages required for compilation - these packages are not kept in source control. At runtime there are a couple of extra dll's which are required. Would it be bad practice to create a VS post-build step which calls NuGet.exe to download these packages and then copies the binaries to the required location? It doesn't look like the intended use of NuGet, but I don't see any obvious flaws with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

I not sure if this would be a good way to do it, but it might solve your problem:

Create a NuGet-package with the DLL's in question as *content*. You should have the following in your nuspec-file:

```
<files>
    <file src="path\to\dll\one.dll" target="content\dlls\one.dll" />
    <file src="path\to\dll\two.dll" target="content\dlls\two.dll" />
</files>
```

When installing this NuGet package in your project, you'll get a folder *dlls* added to the project root. You can then go to the property tab of all the included files and set *Always* for *Copy to Output Directory*.